# asp.net mvc beginform post on wrong page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi i have this project where i have an string parameter on a page the form make the post to

> /booking/confirm

but it need to post to

> /Booking/Confirm?guid=013b0053-5840-4866-97c2-d544d8b6a34c

i could ofcourse just write

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

but i need an class on the form for an jquery function 
so my using looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Booking", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "sigPad"}))
```

Comment: Posts normally don't need to use query string parameters because they send there data in the message body. Can you adjust your service to receive the guid from the message body instead?

Comment: You can add hidden field with your GUID value, then this value will be posted with all other form values.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: The problem is when you make an post and ModelState is not valid it is redirected to /booking/confirm and then you have to click at the link again and type it all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write html without using the helper

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Prods","Products", new { guid=013b0053-5840-4866-97c2-d544d8b6a34c })" method="POST" class="sigPad">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

@using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Booking", new { guid=013b0053-5840-4866-97c2-d544d8b6a34c }